# PHP - PDO - Exception Always Thrown Causing No Active Transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP 8.1.10 and MySQL to try to create a table and then update a record in an existing table using:

```php
try {
    // (optionally) create the migration table
    require_once(__DIR__ . "/migration-migration.php");
    $connection->beginTransaction();

    // create or drop the sugar table
    $sql = "";
    if ($direction === 0) {
        $sql = "DROP TABLE sugar;";
    } else {
        $sql = "
        CREATE TABLE sugar (
            SugarId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            ReadingDate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
            Reading DECIMAL(10,1) NOT NULL,
            CONSTRAINT PK_Sugar_SugarId PRIMARY KEY (SugarId)
        );";
    }
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();

    // upsert the migration record
    $sql = "
    INSERT INTO migration (MigrationName, IsMigrationUp)
    VALUES ('migration-sugar.php', :direction1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE MigrationName = 'migration-sugar.php', IsMigrationUp = :direction2;
    ";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindParam(':direction1', $direction);
    $statement->bindParam(':direction2', $direction);
    $statement->execute();

    $connection->commit();
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $connection->rollBack();
    $returnObject["error"] = "Something unexpected went wrong.";
    $returnObject["exception"] = $exception;
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode($returnObject);
    return;
}
http_response_code(204);
echo json_encode($returnObject);
```

The issue is that an exception is always being thrown which is triggering my `$connection->rollBack();`. The issue there is that the `$connection->commit();` has already been called which is resulting in an Uncaught PDO Exception because there is no active transaction.

What is particularly frustrating is that if I take out the `rollback()`, it is still returning a 500 response, but the exception property of the JSON response is an object where the errorInfo property is null. If I look at my error.log file there is no error being logged (unless I add the `rollback()` back in which case the Uncaught PDO Exception is logged). And if I run my raw SQL in phpMyAdmin, everything runs fine.

What could be causing my catch to be firing with no exception? Is this just a matter of adding a null check in the exception handler? **Update** apparently adding a null check on the exception fails.

Comment: Typically data definition language clauses (DDL) will trigger the database engine to automatically commit. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php#110483

Comment: @shingo - does that mean that I need to execute SQL from my PDO connection to manage transactions instead of using the PDO transaction methods?

Comment: It means you need individually execute CREATE/DROP TABLE.

Comment: @shi shall this page be resolved by a dupe closure or by a posted answer?  It looks like you have provided resolving advice via comment, but the system is not built to identify pages resolved by a comments.

Comment: @mickmackusa I'm not pretty sure if this solves the problem, there're other topics say that auto-commit can also cause it.

Comment: You're hitting [implicit commit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html), one of MySQL lovely peculiarities. What syntax you use to start the transaction is irrelevant.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - really?! jeeze, I was not expecting that. I've been in SQL Server land for a while now I forgot about these MySQL quirks. I think in the meantime I'm just going to forget about wrapping it in a transaction. If it winds up in a weird state then so be it.